# Из-за чего могли возникнуть такие проблемы при компиляции простой программы с использованием Qt4?

Tags: qt, c++

Я только начал изучать Qt4,скачал с официального сайта версию 4.8.4 для MinGW, и по учебнику написал простую программку, которая по нажатию кнопки просто закрывается. Собралось и скомпилировалось всё вроде-бы нормально, но программа вылетает с ошибкой (в подробностях пишет, что имя модуля с ошибкой QtCore4.dll). В консоли компиляции QtCreator пишет что-то такое:

```
Запускается С:\Qt\progs\hello-build-Qt_4_8_4_4_8_4_-_____\debug\hello.exe
Error -RtlWerpReportExeption failed with status code : -1073741823. Will try to launch process directly.
Программа неожиданно завершилась.
```

При попытке запустить программу через файл.exe появляется сообщение, что запуск программы невозможен, так как на компьютере отсутствует libstdc++-6.dll, хотя таковой на месте. Почему так происходит?

Comment: Есть хорошее средство против подобного геморроя. Называется Линукс.

Comment: А сам скомпиленный .exe Вы так просто не запустите. Нужно положить рядом с ним нужны либы: QtCore.dll, QtQui.dll и пр.
П.С. А вообще, я на днях переустанавливал Qt и у меня например дебаггер брался из Visual Studio, a не родной кутешный.

Comment: Хм... добавил я .dll-ки в папку с файлом.exe. На отсутствие чего-либо не жалуется, но всё равно не запускается: пишет, что проблема в QtCored4.dll

Comment: @Corwin: чё, так и пишет:

> проблема в QtCored4.dll, и я вам не скажу какая, сами догадайтесь, хе-хе

Если нет, приводите полное сообщение.

---
Если пишет, что библиотека `libstdc++-6.dll` не найдена, посмотрите, есть ли она в каталоге **из которого запускается программа**. Если есть, гляньте с помощью `depends.exe` в чём проблема.

Comment: @Corwin: 0xc0000005 == Access Violation. Самое время запускать отладчик. Вы, надеюсь, умеете им пользоваться?

---
И ещё, то, что _креш_ произошёл в QtCored4.dll, не означает, что _проблема_ там. Может, вы туда неинициализированный указатель передаёте?

Comment: При помощи Depends Walker обнаружил недостаток следующих dll-ок: gpsvc.dll, sysntfy.dll и ieshims.dll, с нужного сайта скачал и положил куда надо, но вот вторая проблема осталась. Вот что пишет Dependence Walker: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent mode и отмечает красным ieframe.dll и shlwapi.dll проблема, очевидно, в них, но какая - мне не понятно.

Comment: На delay-load можете не обращать внимание, проблема почти всегда не в них. (Delay-load означает, что они может быть когда-нибудь будут загружены.)

Comment: Тем не менее, программа не работает, а винда ту же ошибку выдаёт.

Comment: Если вы получаете Access Violation, проблема уже не с загрузкой модулей. Подключайте отладчик, смотрите, что именно вываливается.

Comment: Там кода-то 12 строк, ошибаться-то негде.